# Can MongoDB aggregation pipeline $gte and $lte work on dates in string format "Y-m-d H:i:s"?

Tags: mongodb

I know from implementation that the method `$gte` and `$lte` work correctly with just dates specified as strings in the format `"Y-m-d"`, what I would like to know if it's possible for the methods to work if I specify the time aswell like thus:

```
"Y-m-d H:i:s"
```

Anyone know if this is possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If H:i:s is always two-digit, i.e. `14:05:15` then it will be ordered correctly.

If it can contain one-digit in any part, i.e. `14:5:15`, then it will not be ordered correctly.

Comment: thanks, managed to get it working. The issue was due to another error in my code.